# IIS/OWA is not handling new SSL Certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, exchange, exchange-2010, outlook-web-app

I recently created a new SSL Certificate and self-signed it via [this tutorial](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/13916.how-to-use-a-self-signed-certificate-in-exchange-2010.aspx).

The new certificate showed up in the list of certificates.  I then assigned IMAP, POP, SMTP & IIS to the certificate.  This switched the certificate on the IIS bindings for port 443 to the newly created certificate.  The problem is, when I use my newly created certificate, then I try to access OWA, I get "Connection Reset" on FireFox.  When I switch back to the old certificate, via bindings in IIS, it works fine.

The only difference is the SSL certificate.  What could cause this?

Comment: What about Outlook with the new certificate?  If Outlook works and OWA doesn't, that will tell you if the problem is with the cert configuration in IIS or not.

Comment: Does this happen in IE as well? I found a nice walk through for testing where the issue might be coming from. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-dont-load-troubleshoot-and-fix-errors

Comment: Same thing happens on IE and FF.  I don't have Outlook.